# access windows shared folder from docker

Tags: 20.04, mount, samba

i am using ubuntu20.04 and docker with same system. I want to access windows shared folder from the docker. I am using GIO. I try like this:

gio mount smb://"PC-NAME"/"FOLDER"

this is working on my OS UBUNTU. But it does not work on the docker(same os).
give an error.

gio: smb://"PC-NAME"/"FOLDER": volume doesn?t implement mount

what I am doing wrong? I also can use another tools than GIO.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [privilege mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) from `docker`. By default docker are missing the capabilities to mount devices, since it requires special privileges.

###### Example:

```
$ docker run --privileged -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: no success at this moment. ubutnu is the name of docker right?